# JSON get a value (very rookie)

Tags: javascript, json

Hello guys I got an URL : https://api.csgofast.com/price/all. 
Now I want to get the value (Price) of a given key (name).

I know there have been some questions about this already but I couldn't get it working and JSON is completely new.

I want it to work in javascript if possible.

I hope u guys can help me out :)

I saw something like this on an other question but couldnt get it working :

```
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan', function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result);
    result.innerText = data.result;
  }
});
```

I got this code now:

```
getJSON('https://api.csgofast.com/price/all', function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    console.log("something went wrong on pricing!");
  } else {
    console.log("item price : " + data['Sticker | Good Game']);

  }
});
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: JSON is just a way how to store objects as strings (the N stands for notation). Basically all you need to know in JS is `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to encode/decode an object to string and vice versa.

Comment: @maraca `xhr.responseType = 'json';` is already parsing it. As for the solution, it's pretty simple. Using the code above, simply replace `data.result` with `data['Sticker | Good Game']`, for example

Comment: Please post your own code to show what you have tried.

Comment: @blex thanks I wanted to know how I could get the value of 1 item

Comment: @lomboboo I got this error Cannot read property 'Sticker | Good Game' of undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "not working"? Because the `alert` shows up.

### Browser

The problem is probably that your `result` is not defined yet. If you have:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

then use

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
```

before your try to change its `innerText`.

[Here is a live example.](https://jsfiddle.net/yc7nasfv/)

### Node.js

If you're running this on Node.js, know that there is a different mechanism to perform HTTP requests. Below is the code you need.

```
var https = require('https');

var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
  https.get(url, function (response) {
    var buffer = '';
    response.on('error', callback);
    response.on('data', function (d) { buffer += d; });
    response.on('end', function () {
      callback(null, JSON.parse(buffer));
    });
  });
};

getJSON('https://api.csgofast.com/price/all', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('item price : ' + data['Sticker | Good Game']);
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that OP just pasted code from some other SO question and apparently without any modification.

Comment: well, this is what I got now but I got this error Cannot read property 'Sticker | Good Game' of undefined.               getJSON('https://api.csgofast.com/price/all', function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    console.log("something went wrong on pricing!");
  } else {
    console.log("item price : " + data['Sticker | Good Game']);
   
  }
});

Comment: @Nick I got this to work with the exact code you posted: https://jsfiddle.net/j0819w5n/

Comment: @RubenVerborgh hmm weird, dont know why I get error undefined then

Comment: @Nick Are you using the _exact_ same code? `data` cannot be `undefined` at this point. (`data['Sticker | Good Game']` can be `undefined` though if there is no field named `Sticker | Good Game`)

Comment: @RubenVerborgh well I use this:     console.log("item price : " + data['Sticker | Good Game']);
istead of alert, but when i do this     console.log("item price : " + data); I also get to see that data is undefined

Comment: @Nick Could you please point to your full code somewhere? Either upload an HTML file, create a gist, or use JSFiddle.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh its literally the same code, I run this javascript file on my VPS so maybe thats why I get an error?

Comment: @Nick How do you run the code? By looking at it from your browser, or running Node.js? If you're looking at it from your browser, it should give the exact same result. Probably there is something different somewhere; if possible, please share the exact file.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh I put the code you had on fiddle in a javascript file and then run it on vps like this: node /root/testscript/test.js (ofcourse instead of alert i use console.log)

Comment: @Nick So you are running this with Node.js. That makes a big difference, because Node.js constructs requests differently than browsers. Next time, mention this in your question :-) Answer updated.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh Ahh sorry didnt know that, very much thanks for the quick responses and help :)